# I use the same books that my sister used

Tags: grammar

> I use the same books that my sister used.

Does this mean the book my sister really used or the same kind of books like the same brands ?

Comment: Books don't have _brands_. They might be copies of the same title, published by the same publisher, or on the same topic.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence can mean one of two things.

1. You're using literally the same books that your sister used, i.e. they're the same physical books, presumably given to you by your sister because she no longer needs them.
2. You're using the same books, but they're different physical copies. Perhaps it's for a class that requires those books and for some reason your sister still wants to hold on to her copies.

The interpretation of the books being the same brand, or on similar topics doesn't really work here. For that situation, as you mentioned in the question, the sentence would be something like:

> I use the same kind of books that my sister used.

If all the books share some common property, e.g. they're all history books.

Or:

> I use the same kinds of books that my sister used.

If the books could be clustered into groups of similar books, such as, books on history, books on politics, etc.